# Subclassing UIButton to set value like tag

Tags: ios, uibutton

I was trying to subclass some UIButtons in oder to obtain a property similar to the button.tag property. In this property I would like to set an MCPeerID. The property must look something like:

```
button.thePeerID = an MCPeerID
if (button.thePeerID == a peer id)...
```

Unfortunately the tag property will only hold numbers. I know I have to add a new file of UIButton type and call it like this:

```
SubclassButton *myButton=[SubclassButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
```

But how do I get the desired property?

Comment: What type is MCPeerID?

Comment: @Cameron provides a reasonable answer about "how" to do this, but you should think more about "why" you want it.  Having seen this type of question before, 10 times out of 10, the answer is that extra data is part of the app's model and doesn't belong hung off a button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll set that property in your header file (subclassButton.h)

```
@interface SubclassButton : UIButton 

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *thePeerId;

@end
```

…then you can access it as you suggested above:

```
myButton.thePeerId = @"abcd";
```

(of course, the type depends on what a McPeerID actually is. adjust accordingly)

Comment: The MCPeerID is an object for multipeer connectivity. It is not a string even if when logged it gives a string type. There is no way to create an MCPeerid from a string, so I have to store the object itself

Comment: in that case: @property (nonatomic, strong) MCPeerid *thePeerId; Since you're creating the subclass, you can add whatever properties and types you need to access.